# jenkins error: This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to update from java 8 to java 11. I was able to update few other projects without an issue.
For this particular project jenkin sonarcube scanner is kept fails and builds an unstable build.  I can build locally without any issues but when I run it on the pipeline, it throws this error.

```
[INFO] Compiling 255 source files to /home/jenkins/<path>/classes
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Skipping <project name>
[INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 34.830 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-02-28T15:02:08+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/47M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project <project name>: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[Pipeline] }
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
```

Has anyone seen this error? How did you resolve it?

Thanks in advance

I tried adding some missing dependencies and I added below to the properties

```
<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

Comment: Which version of java sdk is installed on jenkins server?

Comment: That im not sure. does it change from project to project? or is it same for the pipeline?

Comment: Jenkins executes your maven process in his own enviroment.